# customer sign up form cant get the data in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I created this `form` for customer signup but I can't get the data in database. I dont know what's wrong with this code. Can someone help me and correct this code?

```
<?php
    include 'conn.php';
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $vcustomerid=$_POST[@FCustomerId];
        $vname=$_POST[@FCustomerName];
        $vemail=$_POST[@FEmail];
        $vaddress=$_POST[@FAddress];
        $vphone=$_POST[@FPhone];
        $vusername=$_POST[@FUsername];
        $vpassword=$_POST[@FPassword];
        $query="INSERT INTO customer VALUES('$vname','$vemail','$vaddress','$vphone','$vusername','$vpassword')";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

    <p><strong>CUSTOMER PROFILE</strong></p>
    <table width = "798" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><label for="FName"></label>
    <input name="FName" type="text" id="FName" size="70" maxlength="100"/>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><label for="FAddress"></label>
    <textarea name="FAddress" id="FAddress" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="FEmail" type="text" id="FEmail" size="70" maxlength="100"/>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="FPhone" type="text" id="FPhone" size="70" maxlength="100"/>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>UserName</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="FUsername" type="text" id="FUsername" size="70" maxlength="100"/>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="FPassword" type="text" id="FPassword" size="70" maxlength="100"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <Center>
    <p><button>Sign Up</button></p>
    </center>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Any error output will help.

Comment: you shouldn't be using mysql_query its obsolete.  being that you are tho: three ideas: 1. var_dump($query) to make sure you're setting everything.  2. use mysql_error() to see what happened.  3. you may have a column out of order which you'll discover at step 2.

Comment: What is the error?
Your query should be like this
$query="INSERT INTO customer ('vname', 'vemail', 'vaddress', 'vphone', 'vusername', 'vpassword'      )VALUES('$vname','$vemail','$vaddress','$vphone','$vusername','$vpassword')";